# iOS Populating UITableView with Data from Plist

Tags: ios, uitableview, plist

I am trying to populate a `UTTableView` with the contents of my `Data.plist` file.
I need to load this into an `NSMutableArray`.
This is how far I came:

(View Did Load):

```
    NSString *PlistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Data" ofType:@"plist"];

    Array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:PlistPath];

    [Array addObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Testing 1", @"name", nil]];
```

And of course at `CellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
cell.textLabel.text = [Array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

I wrote this in my `Data.plist` file (picture):

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cs1xd.png]

Now when I run the App. My `TableView` remains empty.

Thanks for your time and help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently your plist's root is set to `Dictionary`. Change that to `array` first.

Then use this code to show the data:

```
cell.textLabel.text = [[Array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"name"];
```