# How to create TableViewCell with subtitle from Plist

Tags: arrays, dictionary, plist, uitableview

I want to create `TableViewCell` with `title and subtitle cell`, Title and subtitle values from my `plist`. Which method needed? How do it?

Since recently started to learn objective. can anyone help me out here? Thanks

**Plist:**

```
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Stations</key>
        <array>
            <dict>
                <key>Title</key>
                <string>F1</string>
                <key>Subtitle</key>
                <string>F1 A</string>
            </dict>
            <dict>
                <key>Title</key>
                <string>F2</string>
                <key>Subtitle</key>
                <string>F2 A</string>
            </dict>
            <dict>
                <key>Title</key>
                <string>F3</string>
                <key>Subtitle</key>
                <string>F3 A</string>
            </dict>
        </array>
    <key>Service center</key>
        <array>
            <dict>
                <key>Title</key>
                <string>F4</string>
                <key>Subtitle</key>
                <string>F4 A</string>
            </dict>
            <dict>
                <key>Title</key>
                <string>F5</string>
                <key>Subtitle</key>
                <string>F5 A</string>
            </dict>
        </array>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the example here:
http://www.ios-blog.co.uk/tutorials/how-to-populate-a-uitableview-from-a-plist-property-list/

Your plist contains a `dict` at the root, so to retrieve the data from the plist you should use:

```
NSDictionary *dictFromPlist = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:
```

And then get the two arrays using (you should create two properties for these arrays):

```
self.stationsArray = dictFromPlist[@"Stations"];
self.serviceCenterArray = dictFromPlist[@"Service center"];
```

Anyway, see how you get on with that. This is a pretty common use case, so there's plenty of good info out there e.g.
[iOS Populating UITableView with Data from Plist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20932578/ios-populating-uitableview-with-data-from-plist)